# neovim switch keymapping

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, multibyte

I am in the process of getting myself to start using neovim instead of vim/vi which has been favorite editor for over 30 years.

For my current use, I need to set keymapping to type characters that have diacritical marks. These are IAST diacritical marks available as keymapping file iast.vim. The keymapping can be switched by typing `set keymapping=iast` The way these keymappings work is you get gīta by literally typing g-ita. Likewise numerous keyboard shortcuts are present in iast.vim

The keyboard mapping works well in vim, but in neovim it works with a caveat. I have to enter the keys really fast to see the diacritical character show up as expected. This is on a Mac. I have experienced the same behavior using iterm2 or alacritty terminal.

Any tips to resolve this?

Comment: Vim and Neovim have different default values for some settings. See `:h 'timeout'` and all that stuff below. Compare the actual values in both your configs.

Answer (score 2):

`set timeoutlen=500` resolves this. Thanks Matt.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and explain why or how `timeoutlen=500` is the appropriate resolution. This will greatly help future readers.